# Count the number of bit strings of length 14 that have exactly seven 0's and neither begin with 11 nor end in 11.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on this question. I tried doing this.
$$
_{14}C_7 - _{12}C_7 - (_{12}C_7 - _{10}C_7) = 1968
$$

Comment: How many are there if you don't care about start or end?  How many are there which do start with 11?  How many end with 11?  How many both start and end with 11?  Apply inclusion-exclusion to conclude.

Comment: @JMoravitz Do I use base 2 then instead of combinations?

Comment: My answer I arrive at agrees with yours.  That is just the logic I used to get there.  I would still use combinations.

Comment: @JMoravitz for example if i get total possible combinations $2^{14}$ and strings that end or start $2^{12}$. How do I find inclusive and exclusive, is it $2^{10}$?

Comment: I left out a phrase which I thought was implied that you seem to be confused by.,  I meant "How many (*bit strings of length 14*) are there (*with exactly seven 0's*) if you don't care about..."  it is, again, $\binom{14}{7}-\binom{12}{7}-\binom{12}{7}+\binom{10}{7}$, exactly as you have written above.  $2^{14}-2^{12}-2^{12}+2^{10}$ would count the number of length 14 bitstrings neither beginning nor ending with 11 where we don't care how many zeroes there are.

Comment: @JMoravitz Does that mean $2^{14} - 2^{12} - 2 ^{12} - _{14}C_7$?

Comment: **Your original answer is fine**.  Stop mixing $2^n$ into the conversation.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, didn't see your update to the previous comment

Comment: Your solution is perfectly correct. Why do you say you're "stuck"? What makes you think there's something wrong with it?

Comment: @bof I was a bit confused when to use base 2 or combinations to solve bit string problems. Now, I think I understand that if there are specific bits in a string then I use combinations and base 2 when there are no specified bits in a string.